# Test menu in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, testing, visual-studio-2012

I use `Visual Studio 2012` and want to know how can I use `Test` menu. I want to have check list for each form that tick check list items when survey deference form test parameter.

Comment: Sorry your VS 2012 Pre Releace or Beta?,i'm this problem yet.I this decided problem for reopen VS 2012 or ReInstall VS 2012 :(

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate edition.

Comment: OK!,It's also I had that problem ,and i this problem decided for reinstall vs 2012.And more i PC bug yet vs 2012(Do not fully worked :(,not working Added referenced and .NET 2 project not fully conversion,and more...)